# Scheduling Data Filter, then Schedule Email to Send Using it's Data Extension

Tags: dataextensions, filters, schedule

I have 4 data filters that my previous supervisor created. We have been manually running all 3 filters daily, then sending the data extension after. I am looking to schedule the data filter to run/generate the data extension and then send the corresponding email. I have tried and I keep getting an error message in ET automation studio.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please include the error message that you are receiving? Just edit your original post and add it there.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the issue. It just says error and does not offer any info or description/message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a [**Filter Activity**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/filter_activity/) for the [**Data Filter**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_filters/).  Once that's done you can add it to the Automation.

Or you can update your User-Initiated Send Definition to send directly to the Data Filter if you don't care about knowing the send counts beforehand.